# How to change voice played by AVSpeechSynthesizer in ios?

Tags: ios, avspeechsynthesizer

I am using `AVSpeechSynthesizer` for playing my TTS string. If I want to change its voice, is there any option?

Comment: NSString *string = @"Hello, World!";
AVSpeechUtterance *utterance = [[AVSpeechUtterance alloc] initWithString:string];
utterance.voice = [AVSpeechSynthesisVoice voiceWithLanguage:@"en-US"];

AVSpeechSynthesizer *speechSynthesizer = [[AVSpeechSynthesizer alloc] init];
[speechSynthesizer speakUtterance:utterance];

Comment: @JoyalClifford I have written this only, but I want to change this voice. :(

Comment: [AVSpeechSynthesisVoice voiceWithLanguage:language]];

Comment: ok changing language changes the voice, too. Thank you @JoyalClifford

Comment: Please don't blindly rollback changes and please use the proper tags.

Comment: Thank you @rmaddy for answer link